# ASP.NET: View is shown without going through controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller

I'm new to MVC so I've been struggling a little bit...
I have this URL.Action:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" href="@Url.Action("Edit", "ControllerName", new { id=item.id })"></a>
```

It is opening the view for "Edit" in a Modal, using bootstrap. The controller is like this:

```
// GET
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{
    mv= bll.Details(id);
    if (mv == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    method(mv);
    return PartialView(mv);
}

// POST:
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(TYPE pMv)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        bll.Edit(pMv);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return PartialView(pMv);
}
```

So I click the link, it opens the modal with the view, I change the data, it saves in the Database, and everything is OK.
The problem is with **Internet Explorer**: if I click again the link to Edit this Item, it opens the view in the model, but without passing through the controller's GET ActionResult, what causes the view to show the previous information, without the changes that I've made.

I can do this to every item, and they will all show they own information (not from the previous item), but without updating the changes that I've made.
If I access the view using it's URL (//localhost:5528/MV/Edit/49), then the information gets updated.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: it is because content is place as html and new data is not fetched every time

Comment: if you use chrome and check the network tab, does it show 304 on the second click?  if so, then you might need to turn off caching in jquery, using something like $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});

Comment: @Slicksim I was using IE to debug Javascript so I changed to Chrome and noticed that it's only happening in IE (it's getting a 304 in the POST), Firefox and Chrome are OK. I did what you've said and now it works! Thanks!!
PS: How do I vote your anwser?

Comment: I've fleshed it out and added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments and for the benefit of others, IE is much more aggressive in it's caching, I personally suspect that is to try and bluff it's way as being as fast as chrome/firefox :)

You can diagnose this by looking in the network/profile tab or iis logs to see if the request is getting a 304 (Content not changed) response.

To fix the issue, just turn of caching for ajax calls by using this in either your _layout, or in each view that needs a fresh reload each time

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
```

Hope this helps others